# Installing gstreamer1.0 on debian wheezy (dependencies libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 and liborc-0.4-0)

Tags: linux, debian, gstreamer

I'm attempting to install gstreamer1.0 on debian wheezy.

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0
```

There are a few dependency errors.  One of which is an incorrect version of libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0

I try to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0
```

I get another dependency error.  This time the error says

```
Depends: liborc-0.4-0 (>= 1:0.4.18) but 1:0.4.16-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

If I try to install/reinstall liborc-0.4-0 with apt-get, it tells me that I already have the newest version.

I've searched and discovered that this has been a problem since the libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 was updated recently on the repos but without the ability to update it with apt-get, I'm not sure how to proceed.  I'm new to debian/linux so any and all help will be great.

Is there a way to get gstreamer1.0 installed on debian wheezy that I don't know about?

Comment: Could you please tell us where you got your `gstreamer1.0` package from? It's not in the wheezy package repos. My guess is that you added some third party repository.Could you please do an `apt-cache policy gstreamer1.0` or give us a link to the tutorial you followed trying to install gstreamer?
Also: Does it need to be GStreamer 1.0 would you be happy with 0.10 as well?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue.  I needed some file updates from the wheezy-backports and I didn't know the commands to utilize this.

The resolution is documented on another forum here: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=117769

Answer (score 0):

This package is not fully tested so it's not available in standard wheezy repo.. However, it's available in wheezy-backports @ https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev

You first need to add wheezy-backports to /etc/apt/sources.list as specified here, http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/#index2h2 and then run following on your system

```
   $ apt-get update && apt-get -t wheezy-backports install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
```